# How can i force method to wait until a callback finishes on swift?

Tags: ios, swift, callback, httprequest

I'm trying to make an http post request,
but the method returns before the dictionary get's filled.

How can i force the method to wait for the callback?

```
func makeRequest()-> [String :AnyObject]{
        var ans : [String :AnyObject] = ["response" : "", "data" : "", "error" : ""]
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: self.url)!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
        if self.jsonIcluded {
            var err: NSError?
            let req = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self.data!, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &err)
            request.HTTPBody = req
        }
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil
            {
                println("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            ans["response"] = response
            ans["data"] = data
            ans["error"] = error
        }
        task.resume()
        return ans
    }
```

Comment: can't you make a synchronous call?

Comment: Add a completion block to the input parameters of makeRequest, and isntead of return, call the completion block after ans["error"]...

Answer (score 0):

NSURLSession is used to make asynchronous requests. If you want to send synchronous requests then use the `NSURLConnection -sendSynchronousRequest:` method.

```
let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)
return reply
```